# Увеличение под размер монитора translate

Tags: html, css, html5

Есть строка которая уменьшает весь обьект.

```
.containerqwe{
 transform:scale(0.4)translate(0,500px)
}
```

Когда захожу в полноэкранный  режим и даю этой строке увеличение

```
:-webkit-full-screen .containerqwe{

    transform:scale(0.8)translate(0,500px);


}
```

Весь обьект увеличивает но на разных мониторах он будет выглядит по разному где то слишком маленьким где то большим как сделать чтобы он увеличивался под размер монитора? может функции transform можно дать какие нибудь такие параметры

```
 height: 15vh; 
  width: 15vw;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через `calc()` и `var()` еще можно было бы провернуть это дело, если бы CSS умел определять текущий размер окна в пикселях. Но он вроде не умеет, поэтому можно пробовать через JS:

`window.innerWidth` дает ширину экрана в пикселях. Умножаем его на 0.15, получаем 15%.

`element.clientWidth` дает ширину указанного элемента. У нас это `demo` и у него ширина-высота изначально заданы 150 пикселей. Разделяем 15% ширины окна на Ширину блока, получаем коэффициент, который можно использовать для `scale();` (если window.innerWidth*0.15 оказывается = 300, то 300 / 150 как раз будет = 2, scale(2) = увеличит в два раза).

[JsFiddle - здесь удобнее будет смотреть (поменяйте размер окна)](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/gvzax36L/)

```js
(function (){

function bubu(){
let demo = document.getElementById('demo');
let coefX = window.innerWidth*0.15/demo.clientWidth;
let coefY = window.innerHeight*0.15/demo.clientHeight;
demo.style.transform = 'scale(' + coefX + ',' + coefY + ')';

//Ненужное демо
let demo1 = document.getElementById('demo1');
demo1.innerHTML = 
'Ширина окна: ' + window.innerWidth + 
', Высота окна: ' + window.innerHeight + 
'<br>Ширина блока: ' + demo.clientWidth + 
', Высота блока:' + demo.clientHeight + 
'<br>Коэфф для scaleX: ' + coefX + 
', Коэфф для scaleY: ' + coefY;
//конец ненужного
}

bubu();
//Каждый раз вызываем функцию при изменении размера окна.
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){ bubu(); });
})();
```

```css
#demo {width: 150px; height: 150px; position: absolute; margin: auto; background-color: red; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="demo1"></div>
<div id="demo">123</div>
```

Comment: Пытался по вашему примеру вот этот элемент от маштабировать но не смог получить точный коэфициент https://codepen.io/Alexander3232/pen/WBrwQj

Comment: как для него вычеслять вот эти параметры?

Comment: let demo = document.getElementById('demo');
let coefX = window.innerWidth*0.15/demo.clientWidth;
let coefY = window.innerHeight*0.15/demo.clientHeight;
demo.style.transform = 'scale(' + coefX + ',' + coefY + ')';

Comment: Хитрый там CSS... для начала надо найти элемент, который уменьшит всю сову через scale хотя бы в CSS. Уже потом, вместо demo - взять этот элемент...

Comment: вот уменьшается вся сова там в самом конце css  #item{

  transform:scale(0.8)translate(0,500px);
                   
}

Comment: Ну у item нет собственного размера, поэтому криво считает... https://codepen.io/-BUBU/pen/KLVgRN - единственное, что смог сделать, и то не до конца) Можно (нужно) вообще убрать Y и привязать только к ширине. А в идеале - переписать всю сову из пикселей в vh и vw ))